# Asp core -Angular 2 -Capturing Headers from initial rendering from server

Tags: angular, http, header, token, httphandler

I have an angular client application which is loaded in asp net core. The initial request which comes from asp net core to angular app gives a few headers , How can i capture those headers in angular to reuse them later. 
     I am able to capture headers or intercept calls which are made by angular , how can i capture header from initial response. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Example of GET headers

```
http
  .get<MyJsonData>('/data.json', {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
    // Here, resp is of type HttpResponse<MyJsonData>.
    // You can inspect its headers:
    console.log(resp.headers.get('X-Custom-Header'));
    // And access the body directly, which is typed as MyJsonData as requested.
    console.log(resp.body.someField);
  });
```

example of POST with headers

```
http
  .post('/api/items/add', body, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token'),
  })
  .subscribe();
```

The HttpHeaders class is immutable, so every set() returns a new instance and applies the changes.

More details https://angular.io/guide/http

Edit: I am not sure what do you mean by using them later - perhaps you can save them to SessionStorage or LocalStorage if you need them after refreshing the page.

Check this also: [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript/220233#220233) might help